# If $f$ is differentiable and $x_0=0$ is asymptote then $\lim_{x\to 0 }f'(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus

How one can prove the following:

Let $\delta>0$. And let $f:(-\delta,\delta)-\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and defined on neighborhood of $x_0=0$, and have asymptote on $x_0=0$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0 }f'(x)=L\in\{\mathbb{R}, \pm\infty\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true: consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ which has an asymptote in $x=0$ but
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x) = +\infty
\quad\neq\quad
\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x) = -\infty
$$
so $\not\exists\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$, unless you consider $\infty=\pm\infty$ which you didn't, since you wrote $L\in\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ so that sign counts...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot because the statement is not true. Consider $f(x)=1/\left|x + \frac x2 \sin\frac1x\right|$. Note that we do have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=+\infty$, but $f'(x)=-\operatorname{sgn}(x)\left(1 + \frac12\sin\frac1x - \frac{1}{2x}\cos\frac1x\right)f^2(x)$, which increasingly oscillates between positive and negative values when $x\to0$.